# Controlling PowerPoint Using Excel-VBA (Minimize etc)

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I just altered my code to make it compatible with all versions of office (hence independent of the PowerPoint 15.0 library). While the code works, I'm running into minor problems I need to address for my work. The code and error are given below. Would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

The new code

```
Dim pptApp As Object
Set pptApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = True
pptApp.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized
```

Error - `Compile Error. Variable not defined.`
Error for - "ppWindowMinimized"

The old code with which the "ppWindowMinimized" worked

```
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
pptApp.Visible = True
pptApp.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized
```

I am facing the same error with the following statement as well for the new code:

```
pptApp.ActiveWindow.viewtype = ppViewNormal
myPPT.SaveAs target_dir, ppSaveAsDefault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Late Binding (http://msofficefun.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/early-binding-vs-late-binding-in-office-vba/) you need to replace `'ppWindowMinimized'` with `'2'`. For normal window state use `'1'` and for maximising the window use `'3'`.

Comment: thanks! but i just realized that there are more problems with not using the ref lib (e.g. a chart gets copied as chart instead of getting copied as a picture despite me specifying it, works find when ref added). I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically add relevant ppt ref lib when the excel is opened.

Comment: It is possible to change the ref lib upon opening the workbook (e.g. http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=267) but this is not a very robust way of dealing with this. Maybe if you send me the code you are using for chart copying I can help you fix it.

Comment: Post the code you're using to copy and paste the chart.  Otherwise we're all just guessing at what the problem might be.